# Bug or standard behavior with FocusEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur, onfocus

When creating a select component with an input text box, I needed the following behavior:
When the field was focused, a list of items would open. On blur event - this list disappeared. But, I came across an unusual problem.

Try to set focus, and try clicking anywhere but in the document!
Example: click on the browser search bar. (It is necessary that the focus from the field disappeared)

Now click anywhere in the document (except the text field!) And pay attention to the array of logs.

```
function App() {
   const [value, setValue] = useState("");
   const [focusEvents, setFocusEvents] = useState([]);

   return (
       <>
           <input
               value={value}
               onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
               onFocus={() => setFocusEvents((state) => [...state, "focus"])}
               onBlur={() => setFocusEvents((state) => [...state, "blur"])}
           />

           <input
               type="button"
               onClick={() => setFocusEvents([])}
               value="clear array"
           />

          <pre>{JSON.stringify(focusEvents)}</pre>
       </>
   );
}
```

I decided to describe it in detail at this link: [The whole problem is described here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lumiere-9y58x?file=/src/App.js)

Has anyone encountered such a problem? How did you solve this?

[The last two logs were called at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMj2.png)

Comment: _“I decided to describe it in detail at this link”_ - a proper problem description, and the [mre] to reproduce it, belong _directly_ into your question. Do not just dump them onto external platforms. (This is a Q&A site, and your question would lose any value to future readers, if the external content ever changed or vanished.)

Comment: @CBroe, I needed to reproduce this problem. I wrote the code and described the instructions exactly there so that the user had to spend less time on it.

Comment: Please do not try and argue about this, but follow the conventions of this site.

Comment: @CBroe, I did as you asked. I apologize for the inconvenience. Now, can we solve this problem?

Comment: _“Now click anywhere in the document (except the text field!) And pay attention to the array of logs.”_ - I am, and _nothing_ happens there. (Tested your live example in Chrome.) Which would leave the question, where/what is the actual problem now.

Comment: @CBroe, You didn't notice that when you click outside the document (if the textfield is focused) the field loses focus and the "blur" log is added to the array. And when you click again on any place in the document (not on the textfield), then 2 values ​​are added to the array: "focus", "blur"

Comment: No, I don’t see that second part happening. It just keeps showing the initial `["focus","blur"]`, nothing else added to it.

Comment: Just tested in Firefox as well - same result, I don’t see what you are saying is happening, happening in there either.

Comment: @CBroe, please try to test it on an external resource. I left a link. There is a detailed description of the instructions. Because, I am still getting this problem. Perhaps you misunderstood me.

Comment: I _am_ testing https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lumiere-9y58x?file=/src/App.js, are you talking about something else?

Comment: @CBroe, Did you follow the instructions?
Step 1: Click on the text field (so that it gets focus)
Step 2: Click anywhere (not in the document!!!). You can make the browser half the window to click on the desktop.
Step 3: Click anywhere in the document (not the text field!!!)

After 3 steps, the array of logs will contain 4 entries: ['focus', 'blur', 'focus', 'blur'] - this is the problem!
Required behavior ['focus', 'blur']